# Timed released content based on user join date. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I'm working on a e-course website. My customers pay a monthly fee to access my courses, they get 2 courses free per month. I'm needing to add a function to where members are granted access to new courses each month. This function should be easy to do, release content based on the time frame from when the customer joined. Does anyone know of a plugin that does it, or how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a plugin that will do this, but there is a function within WordPress that will return the value of the date registered for the current user ID. You could, in theory, use this returned value, along with some simple math, to determine if they have access or not. Without a bit more clarification, I can only offer how I would go about doing this;

```
grab user registered date
is month 2 variable set in database?
-> if yes, skip
-> if no, follow below
..is current date 2 months after registering?
..-> if yes, set new value in database
..-> if no, exit function
is month 4 variable set in database?
etc, etc
```

The above is just one way to do it, and is based on not having any real solid understanding of the way you plan to deliver the video content, if the videos are even within the WordPress installation, etc.